# How to flag values in a series if the cumulative sum is less than a constant in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have a time series where I would like to flag negative values if the cumulative sum is less than 5.
The toy dataset below represents what the series could look like, for simplicity I reused the same values everyday but in the actual dataset this is not the case.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.tile(np.array([1,-1,-2,1,-4,-5,-6,7,-3,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]),8),
             index=pd.date_range(start="2022-01-01", periods=192, freq='H'), columns=['A'])
```

I would like to flag the 1 am - 6am, or the -1 to the -6. Even though after -2 it goes positive for 1 value, I would like it to still be flagged since it doesn't make the cumulative sum go past 5. I don't want the -3 to be flagged because the hour before was larger than 5. Is there any way to accomplish this in python?

```
df['Flag'] = np.where(df['A'] < 0, 1, 0)
```

This works for a lot of days, but fails when I have an hour go slightly positive in the middle of a string of negatives, or when an hour goes slightly negative in  a string of positives.

Sorry if the title is confusing, I hope the explanation is clear.

Edit:
My expected output would be

```
df['flag'] = np.tile(np.array([0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]),8)
```

I define the cumulative sum over the whole day, so it resets on midnight the next day.

Edit2:
I want to flag when the cumulative sum is less than -5, but flag all the values that led to that negative -5. And also reset the cumulative sum when numbers start becoming positive and cumulatively go past 5.

Comment: How do you define the cumulative sum (over whole day?). The logic is unclear, can you provide the full expected output?

Comment: I just added an edit for additional clarification that includes my expected output, but yes just the cumulative sum over the whole day

Comment: your cumsum values are `1   0  -2  -1  -5 -10 -16  -9 -12  -3   7  18...`, so this doesn't match the wanted flag with the "<-5" condition

Comment: You are right. I’m having trouble wording this question, but the expected output is what I want. I want it to stop flagging and reset the cumulative sum at 7 because that value is larger than 5. If the cumulative sum is less than -5 and doesn’t contain a value larger than 5, I want to flag all the values that led to that sum, going back to the first negative value in the series. Does that make sense?

Comment: More or less, I understand the far idea but I don't see the exact logic.